# How to fix: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

How do I fix the runtime error: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1.?

```
def backpropagation(model, y_true, y_pred):
    
    for i in range(1, model.L+1):
        
            model.dL_dw[i] = model.a[i-1] * model.df[i](model.z[i]) * 2 * (model.a[i] - y_true)
            model.dL_db[i] = 1 * model.df[i](model.z[i]) * 2 * (model.a[i] - 1)
        
    return model.dL_dw, model.dL_db
```

Comment: Ive tried transposing, but it just won't work.

Comment: I am working with PyTorch.

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question, so it maximize the change of getting an answer